# Laravel PHP, trying to redirect to an id

Tags: php, forms, laravel, redirect

I am a beginner with php and laravel. I have recently created a form at the bottom of my website, that when you click the submit button it sends the data to an email address.

However if you don't fill it in correctly and click submit it refreshes the page and returns to the top of the page. If you submit the form correctly it goes to /contact.

What I am desperate to do is keep the page at the same point on the website (with the form on the screen) instead of refreshing the screen. Same if the form is submitted correctly I would like the screen to stay still.

Routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');

Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');

Route::get('contact', 
  ['as' => 'contact', 'uses' => 'AboutController@create']);
Route::post('contact', 
  ['as' => 'contact_store', 'uses' => 'AboutController@store']);
```

ContactFormRequest.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ContactFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'number' => 'required',
            'message' => 'required',
        ];
    }
}
```

AboutController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ContactFormRequest;

class AboutController extends Controller
{
        public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.contact');
    }

    public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
    {
        \Mail::send('emails.contact',
            array(
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'number' => $request->get('number'),
                'user_message' => $request->get('message')
                ), function($message)
        {
            $message->from('sketchsitestest@gmail.com');
            $message->to('sketchsitestest@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('Testing');
        });

        return \Redirect::route('contact')->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
    }
}
```

contact.blade.php

```
<div class="one-half">
    <ul>
        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>

    {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'contact_store', 'class' => 'form')) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('name', null, 
            array('required', 
                  'class'=>'form-control', 
                  'placeholder'=>'Your name')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('email', null, 
            array('required', 
                  'class'=>'form-control', 
                  'placeholder'=>'Your e-mail address')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::number('number', null, 
            array('required', 
                  'class'=>'form-control', 
                  'placeholder'=>'Your Number')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::text('message', null, 
            array('required', 
                  'class'=>'form-control', 
                  'placeholder'=>'Your message')) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Contact Us!', 
          array('class'=>'form-button btn btn-primary')) !!}
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

I am also new to using stackoverflow, so I apologise ahead if I have missed anything or done anything incorrectly. Please let me know if you need anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Can't really understand your problem, but try to add this in your `store()` method:

```
return \Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
```

But it looks like you want to submit/validate your forms without refreshing the page, so the only solution for this is to use AJAX requests.

Comment: Hi Artur, thank you for your answer. I have added that code to the store method and it just did the same as before. However "But it looks like you want to submit/validate your forms without refreshing the page, so the only solution for this is to use AJAX requests." this is correct so I will look into AJAX requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can be something. Using the `validation` helper.

```
function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
    {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'number' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required',
    ]);

    // If !$this->validate Laravel will automatic return to the previous page (the form page)
    // And you can grab the errors with $errors->first('name'), $errors->first('email') etc

        \Mail::send('emails.contact',
            array(
                'name' => $request->get('name'),
                'email' => $request->get('email'),
                'number' => $request->get('number'),
                'user_message' => $request->get('message')
                ), function($message)
        {
            $message->from('sketchsitestest@gmail.com');
            $message->to('sketchsitestest@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('Testing');
        });

        return \Redirect::route('contact')->with('message', 'Thanks for contacting us!');
    }
```

Grab the errors like this:

```
@if ($errors->has('message'))
    <span class="help-block">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('message') }}</strong>
    </span>
@endif
```

Here you the docs about the [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation), if you are using Laravel 5.3

Comment: Thanks for your answer Adam. I have changed my code to yours above and it didn't change anything. Apologies I must of explain my error incorrectly.

What I am trying to do is make it that when the web user clicks submit whether it be successfully entered/not the page either; doesn't refresh so the user can see the message that says you have completed the form correctly/not. Or the page refreshes but redirects the user to the div id. e.g. if you have a button when you click it, you can make it go to an id further down the page.